# Svelte route to blog article with data

Tags: javascript, svelte

I'm testing Svelte and one of the things I'm trying to do is create a blog. I'm keeping it simple, all I want is to click in a link an open an article.

I only have three files:

- home.svelte
- blog.svelte
- article.svelte

**Home.svelte**

```
<script>
    import { Router, Route, Link } from "svelte-navigator";
    import Blog from "./Blog.svelte";
    import Article from "./Article.svelte";
</script>
<main>
    <Router primary={false}>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
                <Link to="blog">Blog</Link>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <Route path="/">
            <h1>Welcome to my beautiful website!</h1>
        </Route>
        <Route path="blog" component={Blog} />
        <Route path="blog/article/*" component={Article}/>
    </Router>
</main>
```

**Blog.svelte**

```
<script>
    import { Router, Route, Link } from "svelte-navigator";

    const articles = 
    [
        {id: 1, title: 'Sample title', description: 'Sample description' },
        {id: 2, title: 'Sample title 2x', description: 'Sample description 2x' },
    ];
</script>
<h1>List of articles</h1>
<ul>
    {#each articles as article}
        <li>
            <Link to="article/{article.id}">{article.title}</Link>                        
        </li>
    {/each}
</ul>
```

**Article.svelte**

```
<script>
    export let title;
    export let description;
</script>
<h1>{title}</h1>
<p>{description}</p>
```

My problems:

1. When opening the URL `blog/article/1` it shows `undefined` in both `title` and `description`
2. The point 1. makes sense, since I'm not passing anywhere values to the article route, how do I do it?
3. It doesn't make sense to me that in the `home.svelte` I have to declare the route of article, I think it should be declared in the `blog.svelte`, however, if I do that, the article route is not loaded once I try to navigate to it.

I have tried to pass data as argument but doesn't seem to work:

```
<Link to="article/{article.id}" title={article.title}>{article.title}</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

From svelte-navigator documentation, the right way is one of:

```
<Route path="blog/:id" component="{Article}" />
<Route path="blog/:id" let:params>
    <Article id="{params.id}" />
</Route>
```

You will the receive a props named id in your Article component. You'll have to get the title & description out of this id (through a basic import or a http fetch or something else).

I don't know your whole project but I highly recomand you to have a look at svelte-kit (routing & server extension of svelte that can generate static site if you need) which handles routing natively. You can then use mdsvex or svelte-markdown as a way to display markdown as html:

- the first one is better if your articles are file based
- the second one is better if your article are stored in a database.

Comment: Yeah, later I found out I can use that approach, however, it doesn't make much sense to me. 

If the articles are being fetch in the first route and since this uses a SPA approach, we should be able to send parameters to the next route (in this case the article itself) through <Link>. We shouldn't be forced to fetch again the article data by ID.

I was just testing the purpose of SPA and I was thinking about using Laravel for API and Svelte for frontend.

Comment: You might not fetch the same amount of data in your blog list component (title, date, short description) and in your articles (the full article). If you want to fetch all the data in one request, I guess you can still populate a svelte store and access it with the given id (svelte store doc: https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store)

Comment: Yesterday I end up trying the writable/readble, but got no where to be honest. But okay, it seems this could be the only solution? The objective is to reduce significantly the amount of requests.

Comment: What about loading the articles in the component where you have your `<Router>` defined?

Comment: The <Router> is defined in the home.svelte as you can see in the example. Loading the articles there wouldn't make much sense since the user might not visit the blog. I tried to put a <Router> inside the blog.svelte, which for me would make sense, but nothing happens / doesn't work.